# Does DynamoDB support jsonp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I took a look through the documentation, but couldn't find it. Can anybody who has used the service answer this?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB objects' attributes can be int, string, int set or string set.
JSONP is string representing a javascript code that can be parsed.

What is the use you intend for it? What object are you going to store?
Are you invoking an AJAX call to the dynamodb api to retrieve an element and you want that element to follow JSONP pattern? or you wish to call DynamoDB in your server (perhaps using a servlet) and prepare a JSONP object to be sent to the client

Comment: JSONP is a way to retrieve data, not a format for the data itself. It was designed primarly to circumvent the cross-domain protections of a web browser. The question has nothing to do with what is store din the database, but likely rather whether it can be accessed via JSONP, allowing use of DynamoDB directly from a web page without a server component.